# Problems with unhashable list in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

2 days ago i started coding a converter String to HEX. Now i have that code

```
HEXV = {"A":"41","a":"","B":"42","b":"","C":"43","c":"","D":"44","d":"","E":"45","e":"","F":"46","f":"","G":"47","g":"","H":"48","h":"","I":"49","i":"","J":"","j":"","K":"","k":"","L":"","l":"","M":"","m":"","N":"","n":"","O":"","o":"","P":"","p":"","Q":"","q":"","R":"","r":"","S":"","s":"","T":"","t":"","U":"","u":"","V":"","v":"","W":"","w":"","X":"","x":"","Y":"","y":"","Z":"","z":""}
CHAR = []

def loop():
    n = 0
    if CHAR[n] in HEXV:
        print(HEXV.get(CHAR[n]))
        n += 1

i = input(str('Insert Phrase:'))

l = list(i)
CHAR.append(l)

loop()
```

with that error

```
C:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39>C:/Users/Pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/Pc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/codes/HEXCODE Converter.py"
Insert Phrase:A
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\codes\HEXCODE Converter.py", line 16, in <module>
    loop()
  File "c:\Users\Pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\codes\HEXCODE Converter.py", line 7, in loop     
    if CHAR[n] in HEXV:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

whetever i change the code it don't solve.
i already browsed it but i couldn't solve it and if you would help me I would be grateful

Comment: The first step of debugging would be print out `CHAR[n]` and see what it is. You'll spot what your issue is.

Comment: "CHAR[n]" is a list and with "in" you ask if this list is a key of a dictionary but it can't be because a list is not hashable while dictionary keys have to be hashable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` returns a string

```
> i = input('Insert Phrase:')
> Insert Phrase:A
> i
'A'
```

You made that a list

```
> l = list(i)
> l
['A']
```

Then appended that to a list `CHAR`

```
> CHAR = []
> CHAR.append(l)
> CHAR
[['A']]
```

So in your function `loop` *(which doesn't actually loop btw)* you access the nth value which will always be 0 because you're not looping:

```
> n = 0
> CHAR[n]
['A']
```

And list's are not hashable so

```
> CHAR[n] in HEXV
# which is actually this
> ['A'] in HEXV
```

Gives you the error.

What you could do is use `CHAR.extend(l)` instead of `CHAR.append(l)` or just pass the actual list to loop. But you need to re-evaluate your code in general because I don't believe this will do what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer in a way that will hopefully help you to identify the specific error you have asked about, taking your code sample at face value and not commenting on its overall logic or design (since that's not the main point of your question, I have not focused on it).

`CHAR` is a list containing another list (`l`) and `HEXV` is a dict. The Python list data type is indeed not hashable (see the Python docs for dict [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) and for hashable [here](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable)), and furthermore, each key in `HEXV` is a string of length 1, not a list. Consider using just the first character of `CHAR[n]` when checking for presence in HEXV:

```py
if CHAR[n][0] in HEXV:
```